# Horizontal flip RGB tuple list python

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples, reverse

I am trying to make an image do a horizontal flip in python. I have the "image" in a text file that contained all of the RBG values. I put these RGB values into tuples so that I could change the colors / do things to the image. I figured out how to do a Vertical flip by doing

```
def apply_vertical_flip(image_2dlist, outfile):
'''
Accepts a 2-dimensional list of tuples and an output file object
Flips the image data in image_2dlist vertically
'''
    print("\nOpening ny.ppm for reading and ny_verical_flip.ppm for writing...\n")

    for i in range(len(image_2dlist)):
        image_2dlist.reverse()

    print(image_2dlist)
```

but for horizontal I need to flip the contents of each line, instead of the whole file. I'm really stuck, and I don't know how to change the contents of each line.

essientally this is what I need to happen

`(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9), (10,11,12)`

`(13,14,15) (16,17,18)` (the lengths of the line could be different)

into

`(10,11,12), (7,8,9), (4,5,6), (1,2,3)`

`(18,17,16), (13,14,15)`

for some reason the tuples are being printed on the same line, but i put a \n where the break should be (not in the code, just stack overflow)

Comment: What exactly is a "line" here?

Comment: `for i in range(len(image_2dlist)):` why this loop?

Comment: that loops through the entire image file @njzk2, i only proved a small snipit of what the image file looks like

Comment: or theoretically looks like

Comment: sorry i fixed it, stack overflow was causing it to look like everything was on one line @AbidHasan

Comment: @sarahcampolt actually it doesn't. You are not using `i` inside the loop, so what you are doing is simply reversing the image n times.

Comment: What data structure are you using? How do you know when a line ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are approaching this wrong by only using 1 list to store your tuples.

An image is a 4 sided shape with pixels that align to a grid like structure; and presumably, the line that you describe is a row of that grid.

Why not use a 2D list that represents the pixels of the image and then you could simplify the calculations/processing of the image that you want to achieve. Additionally, doing it this way eliminates the need to be concerned about image size and/or width/height.

For example;

```
w, h = img.width, img.height;
pixels = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)] 
# Fill the pixels here
# Flip the image horizontally
for row in grid:
    row.reverse()
```

Depending on your data structure, which you have not disclosed you may have to build the initial 2D array in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 0):

This would flip each row.

```
image = (((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(10,11,12)),((13,14,15),(16,17,18)))
image_Hflip = tuple([i[::-1] for i in image])

print image_Hflip
```

> (((10, 11, 12), (7, 8, 9), (4, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3)), ((16, 17, 18), (13, 14, 15)))

Although I'm sure there are better ways to represent image data.